# How do I make Xcode consider the values of my defines?

Tags: c, xcode

How can I make Xcode consider the values of my defines to fold my code properly? Xcode seems to consider some things that aren't compile as part of the code -- with causes some issues for me :(

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LIE_TO_THE_USER   1

void foobar(int argc)
{ // A
#if LIE_TO_THE_USER
    if (0) { // B
#else
    if (argc > 0) { // C
#endif
        printf("argc is greater than 0\n");
    } // D
    else
    { // E
        printf("argc is not greater than 0\n");
    } // F
} // G

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    foobar(argc);
    return 0;
}
```

This code compiles... but is a pain to work with.

As far as Xcode is concerned, it folds brackets C and D together, E and F together, and folds C and G together (instead of folding A and G). Additionally, anything declared after the `#if #else #endif` (so just the `main` is this case) doesn't show up in this case.

In Visual Studio, it would just grey out the `if (argc> 0 ) { // C` and ignore it. But Xcode seems to consider it part of the code. I have found 2 workarounds:

```
void foobar(int argc)
{
#if LIE_TO_THE_USER
    if (0)
#else
    if (argc > 0)
#endif
    {
        printf("argc is greater than 0\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("argc is not greater than 0\n");
    }
}

///  OR

void foobar(int argc)
{
#if LIE_TO_THE_USER
    if (0) {
#else
    if (argc > 0) {
#endif
        printf("argc is greater than 0\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("argc is not greater than 0\n");
    }
#if 0
    }
#endif
}
```

However, this problem is veeeeery frequent in my project. So I would like to find to solve this problem automatically without having to worry about adding workarounds. Does anyone know a way to configure Xcode to ignore lines such as `if (argc > 0) {`?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Did you try `#ifdef`? or `#if LIE_TO_THE_USER == 1`

Comment: Is this a representative example? Would an alternative solution that conditionally compiles the content of `if` rather than the entire `if` work for your situation?

Comment: It looks like the bracket reader can't parse the #defines.  You could bracket whole alternative functions.  (Might not be so bad if the alt. are trivial.)

Comment: Sometimes it's simpler to just `#define` a value which you use as a condition in the `if`.  Eg, `if (LIE_TO_THE_USER || (argc > 0))`.  Of course, you have to make sure LIE_TO_THE_USER is always defined one way or the other.  And, in place of `#if`, you can use `if (LIE_TO_THE_USER)`.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the reasons macros are horrible; You can arbitrarily mess with the token stream and aren't bound to respect the language's structure.

Visual Studio is just completely ignoring whatever is eaten by the preprocessor, which means it reliably understands the structure of the code under the current defines but has no understanding of the code that's disabled. Xcode is trying to be smarter and to understand the entire program, but this works poorly when you use macros that really subvert the language's structure.

C++ is already hard enough for tools to work with, and the fundamental nature of the preprocessor makes it worse by essentially making it so that the same C++ source can produce arbitrarily many programs. You can avoid this problem by minimizing use of the preprocessor, and restricting uses to the simplest and most conventional, so that tools are likely to understand them.

---

In this case I think I would go with something like:

```
void foobar(int argc)
{
    static constexpr bool tell_the_truth = false;

    if (tell_the_truth && argc > 0)
    {
        printf("argc is greater than 0\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("argc is not greater than 0\n");
    }
}
```

Or if you want to be able to configure this from the compilation command you can use:

```
static constexpr bool tell_the_truth = !LIE_TO_THE_USER
```

So that you can use a flag such as `-DLIE_TO_THE_USER=true` or `-DLIE_TO_THE_USER=false`.

The benefit of this approach is that tools' understanding of this program, the AST, actually represents the intended program and doesn't fundamentally change between configurations.

Comment: Good answer. This is actually how me and my co-workers write code of our own. However we use a lot of 3rd party code that uses directives all over the place so this solution isn't always possible depending on the circumstances. I don't like it, but it's unavoidable so I just need to deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the amount of code that looks like conditional compilation to Xcode by using a conditionally compiled macro, like this:

```
#define LIE_TO_THE_USER   1
...
#if LIE_TO_THE_USER
    #define CONDITIONAL_LIE(A,B) (A)
#else
    #define CONDITIONAL_LIE(A,B) (B)
#endif
```

With this macro in hand, you can rewrite your `if` as follows:

```
if (CONDITIONAL_LIE(0, argc > 0))
{
    printf("argc is greater than 0\n");
}
else
{
    printf("argc is not greater than 0\n");
}
```

The code would conditionally compile into the same output, but Xcode would think it's a regular `if`. This also looks cleaner to the reader.

Comment: True. It is cleaner - I like this answer. However, it still means I need to tweak every place where this occurs, which I don't have the time to do. Also, here where I work, we prefer to add lines to 3rd party code as oppose to changing lines because it makes merging a patch easier - hence the reason for taking the approach with directives.